# Как в Laravel сделать двух уровненную аутентификацию?

Tags: laravel

Нужно чтобы  сперва зарегистрироваться как пользователь  потом для менеджеров сделать возможность  аутентификации второй раз.

После аутентификации как менеджер при использовании приложения он  уже больше не проходит первую аутентификацию сразу идет ко второму.

Как  сделать двух уровненную аутентификацию?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ это отсылать смс с кодом на телефон, пользователь должен ввести код в форму входа чтобы войти, у кода маленький срок жизни, секунд 25, например.

[Вот пример](https://medium.com/@ryanlebel/add-two-factor-authentication-to-your-laravel-5-application-in-6-steps-ba1a7bc0f404) и [вот](https://www.sitepoint.com/secure-laravel-apps-2fa-via-sms/) еще пример, как работает видно на гифке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также есть популярный пакет для этого [google2fa-laravel](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/google2fa-laravel.), совместимый с Google Authenticator, там есть версия и просто под php, вот [DEMO](https://pragmarx.com/playground/google2fa#/).